# A cool rhyme to maybe pass some time :)

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

Should be really easy, but more to come,
Answer my riddle for some midday fun :).

The giver of power in sometimes under an hour,
You tote me around else ones mood might sour.

So in your pocket I sit,
What once was dead is now brightly lit.

What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Please don't include the answers in the question. Thank you! :)

Comment: OK thanks @mithrandir, i searched around the meta and could not find anything about adding the answer to a question in spoiler markup. It's common place for one to write down the answer or answers to a riddle or original work and i did not know how that transfers into the cyber world. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My immediate thought for this was

> A portable USB charger—[something like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZZYBAI2)

I noticed from the edit history you might have had something slightly different in mind, but I think my take on it is more fitting (though does still require your take on it to work) ...